# при получении поля из БД возвращается null

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Я хочу добавить аватарку профиля, для этого я добавил поле image_filename. При post-методе, когда я выполняю save(), поле сохраняется и в базе данных отображается то, что нужно, но когда я выполняю getImageFilename(), то получаю null, в чем может быть проблема?

post-method:

```
@PostMapping("changeAvatar")
    public String changeAvatar(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                               @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File previousAvatar = new File(uploadPath + "/profile-images/" + user.getImageFilename());
        previousAvatar.delete();

        if (file != null && !Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()).isEmpty()){
            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath + "/profile-images");
            if (!uploadDir.exists()){
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }
            String fileName = UUID.randomUUID() + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();
            file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath + "/profile-images/" + fileName));
            user.setImageFilename(fileName);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
        **System.out.println(user.getImageFilename());**
        return "redirect:/profile";
    }
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sweater_user")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password should not be empty")
    private String password;

    @Email(message = "Email is not correct")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email should not be empty")
    private String email;

    private String activationCode;

    private boolean active;

    private String imageFilename;
    
public User(String username, String password, String email, String activationCode, boolean active, Collection<Role> roles, String imageFilename) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.activationCode = activationCode;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.imageFilename = imageFilename;
    }

    public User() {
    }
    ...
```

Проблема конкретно с полем imageFilename

После выполнения save()

[image: После выполнения save()]

После System.out.println()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас есть сеттер для этого свойства?

Comment: В прикрепленном методе я сразу сетаю, потом сохраняю и все отлично работает, но с геттером какие-то проблемы